# Check if limit exists and its value

Tags: limits

How to check if this limit exists: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}{ \frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^3}}$$

Can I convert it to polar form ?
$$\frac{r^8 (\cos^4 (\theta)\sin^4(\theta)}{r^6 (\cos^6 (\theta) + r^6 \sin^{12} (\theta))} = \frac{r^2}{\cos^6(\theta) + 0} = 0$$

Comment: How do you get that first equality!?

Comment: from formula $ x= rcos(\theta), y = rsin (\theta)$

Comment: Where did the cosines and sines go off to?

Comment: I mistrust the denominator on the leftmost part of the equation. $(a+b)^3 \ne a^3 + b^3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not exist. 
If we appoach along either $x=0$ or $y=0$ we get a limit of zero, if we approach along $x=t^2$, $y=t$ we get a limit of $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: How did you knew what values for x and y choose? ($t$,$t^2$)

Comment: You try to make the top and bottom homogenous of the same degree, plus someone else mentioned it in their comments...

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x(t)=t^2$, $y(t)=t$, so that the fraction behaves, as $t \to 0$, like a nonzero constant.